# Calling value of django tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I am currently working on a beginner level project in django. I want to be able to pass the value of my django tag `{{total_value}}` in javascript in the similitude of this `total: document.getElementById("total").value ,`

I tried using `var total = {{total_value}};` and passed total but it didn't work. Can someone help me out.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: if total_value is working fine in html then try `var total = "{{ total_value }}";`

Comment: Yes, I did that and it wouldn't work. Thanx for your response.

Comment: please share your html, view, urls and models.py file

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Instead of using `document.getElementById("total").value` I gave this (`{{total_value}}`) and id and used `document.getElementById("total_id").textContent;`.

I hope it helps someone too